# Turning on Presentation Mode in Windows?

Tags: windows-vista

Windows Vista has "Presentation Mode", which you can turn on with the Mobility Center.

How can I turn it on programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I found is to call `presentationsettings.exe` with `/start` or `/stop` directly.

I also found this link that describes how to activate presentation mode on desktop PCs: http://www.dubuque.k12.ia.us/it/mobilitycenter/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old, but I found this wasn't working from a third party program, because cmd wasn't inheriting the environment, therefore these weren't working like they would from the Run Box:

- `PresentationSettings`
- `PresentationSettings /start`
- `PresentationSettings /stop`

However, using powershell to spawn a new environment, I was able to invoke it programmatically with the following commands:

- `Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/c PresentationSettings"` # to spawn
  a GUI
- `Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/c PresentationSettings /start" -NoNewWindow` # execute with no gui, but the icon appears in the tray
- `Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/c PresentationSettings /stop" -NoNewWindow` # execute with no gui, but the icon disappears from the tray after it has been started.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fill your need:  [link text](http://blogs.msdn.com/kaevans/archive/2006/09/25/770484.aspx)

Comment: That's how to detect that it's on. How do I turn it on (programmatically)?