# How to achieve presentation mode-like behavior on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows

I am developing a desktop application for Windows 7 which has full screen mode. I would like to be able to disable any kind of notification (like system tray balloons, Windows update, etc.), while the user is in the full screen mode.

Is there a way to easily achieve this in .NET (it is a WPF app)?

(I thought of using the built-in presentation mode for this, but I couldn't figure out a way to turn it on programatically (I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251104/turning-on-presentation-mode-in-windows) question, but the link in the answer describes only how to *query* the presentation mode, and not how to turn it on).)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning on Presentation Mode in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251104/turning-on-presentation-mode-in-windows)

Comment: @RowlandShaw: If you would have read either this question or the one you proposed as duplicate you would have known that it is NOT a duplicate and the OP even says so in his question!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth are you not asking "How can I turn it on programmatically?" then?

Comment: @RowlandShaw: Oh my. Really? (1) I am asking nothing, Mark is asking. (2) The question you linked asks the same thing, *but without an answer*!

Comment: @RowlandShaw: The linked question is specifically about Presentation Mode. I do not insist on using that, I am interested in any other method to achieve a similar result.

Comment: If you don't like the answers on an existing question, you shouldn't ask it again, but you can [offer a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) (requires 75 rep) on the existing question. A quick glance at the Win32 API suggests the answer is going to be "you can't" though.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: I write again: I am NOT asking the same thing. I am interested in ANY possible method to disable notifications in Windows (for which presentation mode would be ONE possible solution if it could be turned on programatically). I put parantheses around the last paragraph of my question to make it more obvious.